# Python requests with redirection on Heroku

Tags: python, redirect, heroku, python-requests, http-headers

I'm making a get request with the requests module of Python. This request returns a 302 code and redirects to another url, from local I am able to capture that new url with:

```
r = requests.get(URL)
finalURL = r.url
```

But when this code is executed in Heroku, the redirection is not carried out and the original url is returned to me.

I've tried everything, including forcing the redirection with this code:

```
r = requests.get(URL, allow_redirects=True)
```

I have also tried to pick up the url from the response headers, such as location or X-Originating-URL, but when the request is made from Heroku, the response does not return those values in the header.

Comment: There's no baked-in reason for this to behave differently on Heroku. Can you share an example URL?

Comment: maybe server doesn't like Heroku servers and it blocks all requests.

Answer (score 0):

Redirects are on by default, try viewing content of it, there has to be something that is redirecting u also u can go try and fiddle it.